# Spring Boot Security - Encoded password does not look like BCrypt/Ecommence Method Failed

Tags: java, spring, jwt, bcrypt, boot

I'm new in Java/Spring boot and I'm doing a login with jwt.

What happens is that I got well to the part of creating users, the issue is that when I want to log in postman I get "401 bad credentials" and in the netbeans console I get Encoded password does not look like Bcrypt and I fail the commence method.

I read my code like crazy and still can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Authcontroller.java

```
java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@CrossOrigin
public class AuthController {
    
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    RolService rolService;
    
    @Autowired
    JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    
    @PostMapping("/new")
    public ResponseEntity<?> nuevo(@Valid @RequestBody NewUser newUser, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return new ResponseEntity(new Msg("Campos o email invÃ¡lido"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        
        if(userService.existsByUsername(newUser.getUsername))
            return new ResponseEntity(new Msg("Nombre de usuario existente"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        
        if(userService.existsByEmail(newUser.getEmail))
            return new ResponseEntity(new Msg("Email existente"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        
        User user = new User(newUser.getName(), newUser.getUsername(), newUser.getEmail(), passwordEncoder.encode(newUser.getPassword()));
        
        Set<Rol> roles = new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(rolService.getByRolName(RolName.ROLE_USER).get());
        
        if(newUser.getRoles().contains("admin"))
            roles.add(rolService.getByRolName(RolName.ROLE_ADMIN).get());
        
        user.setRoles(roles);
        userService.save(user);
        
        return new ResponseEntity(new Msg("usuario guardado"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<JwtDto> login (@Valid @RequestBody UserLogin userLogin, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return new ResponseEntity(new Msg("Campos mal ingresados"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        userLogin.getUsername(), userLogin.getPassword()));
        
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        
        String jwt = jwtProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        
        JwtDto jwtDto = new JwtDto(jwt, userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
        
        return new ResponseEntity(jwtDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    
}
```

MainSecurity.java

```
java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class MainSecurity {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    JwtEntryPoint jwtEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you aren't storing bcrypt encoded passwords in your database, but the configuration is expecting them. Either that or the password hashes are invalid. When you register a new user, you should make sure the password is hashed using bcrypt before you store the user.

Comment: The code that is in your controller should be in a service but alas. What does your `UserService.save` method do? What does your `User` entity look like, how are you storing things in the dabase?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not actually storing `bcrypt` encoded passwords in your database.

However, the system is expecting them. Either that or the password hashes are invalid. When you register a new user, you should make sure the password is hashed using `bcrypt` before you store the user.

Try checking your database manually first, by looking into the `UserEntity` you may have created on the corresponding table.

If the `password` is not being encrypted, make sure it is being used by a `passwordEncoder()` method which should in turn be using a `BCryptPasswordEncoder` object to actually encode your input password.

Hope it helped!!